# rm: "/usr/local/pulse/libwebp.so.6": File or directory does ot exist

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 from 18.04. I didn't realize that Pulse Secure don't work in 20.04, so I tried to make a workaround and it started from console (not from app icon). My college gave us a .py config file, so I tried to open it and seems the installation went good but the profile didnt appear.
I tried to open it again and failed so I tried to install again pulse.
Now when I try to install the .deb file with "dpkg -i" or when I try to uninstall the package "pulse", this error appear:
rm: cannot delete '/usr/local/pulse/libwebp.so.6': File or directory does not exist